# Why does Season 5 have only 20 episodes?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

*Star Wars: the Clone Wars* Season 5 only contains 20 episodes when Seasons 1-4 all contained 22. There was no reason given, and there was a whole arc revolving around Rush Clovis that was planned. Is there any official reason given as to why?

Comment: They were running out of story...

Comment: Apparently, they were *not* running out of story. Work was done on 22 more episodes, [and they will be released next year](http://www.comingsoon.net/news/tvnews.php?id=110133).

Answer (score 1):

The series was announced to be "winding down" by episode 20 of season 5, so it stands to reason that the show was effectively coming to a close.  Also, at the same time Lucasfilm announced a "new direction" in their animation programming beginning with a new series in an era that has not yet been explored.

Source:  http://starwars.com/news/a-new-direction-for-lucasfilm-animation.html